# Guest Entries plugin - set parent entry if using section

Tags: guest-entries, plugin-guestentries

As the title suggests, is it possible to pass an entry ID in order to set a parent for the submitted entry?

Comment: Have you tried to include a `parentId` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Guest Entries plugin checks for a `parentId` value in POST and passes that on to `saveElement`, so that should be all you need to do: https://github.com/craftcms/guest-entries/blob/v2/src/controllers/SaveController.php#L216